# Succinct version of simplexml/xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Currently I have:

```
$content =  ($propXml->xpath('//content/section[@name="accommodations"]/content'));
$content = is_array($content) && (count($content)>0)?(string)$content[0]:false;
echo $content;
```

Is there a more succinct way of doing this? It would be shorter if PHP had the ability to automatically access an assigned array, but I have to reassign and check for the length...

Comment: +1 learned a new word: succinct :)

Comment: Couldn't you shorten that to `$content = isset($content[0]) ? (string) $content[0] : false;`? `isset($content[0])` should fail on a boolean.

Comment: @meder: It's a fair question, but not about XPath expression... Please, retag.

Comment: @Alejandro - wow I've never seen someone downvote for tagging "improperly"

Comment: @meder: It's not about downvoting, but keeping tags relevant.

Comment: @Alejandro - there's no way adding an additional tag when it's still somewhat relevant deserves a downvote. Not gonna edit. If someone in the future decides to ask the same question, they might google and the xpath in my post might bring it higher up in the results, xpath is still being used. I would have not tagged it `php` and `simplexml` if it was strictly an xpath question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make that shorter but it all depends on what you're doing in your script. I'm not shocked by that operation taking 3 lines of code but anyway, here are a few ideas that can make your code shorter, sometimes at the price of decreased readability:

- Use `empty()`

  ```
  $content = (!empty($content)) ? (string) $content[0] : false;
  ```
- Echo the node directly: (it automatically gets cast as a string)

  ```
  echo (!empty($content)) ? $content[0] : '';
  ```
- Use `array_shift()` to get the first element of an array. **(attention, it *does* modify the array. If it was the last element, you could use `end()` instead)**

  ```
  echo array_shift($propXml->xpath('//content/section[@name="accommodations"]/content'));
  ```